# Mongoose: $inc increments the field by double the value specified

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a document:

```
{
    "_id" : "5ec8f4454868d203e8e624a3",
    "username" : "Jamie",
    "points" : 25, 
}
```

I'm using $inc to increment 'points':

```
model.updateOne({username: "Jamie"},{$inc:{points:5}})
```

This results in following:

```
{
    "_id" : "5ec8f4454868d203e8e624a3",
    "username" : "Jamie",
    "points" : 35, 
}
```

Any idea why it is incrementing twice the specified value?

Here's the actual code:

```
app.post("/signup", function(req, resp){
  var parent_id;
  globalvarCollection.findOne({serial:1}, 'current_level', function(doc){
  try{
    current_level=doc.current_level;
    userCollection.countDocuments({level:current_level}, function(doc2){
      userCollection.findOne({level:current_level-1, ttl_chldrn:{$lt:6}}, 'ref_id', function(doc3){
        parent_id=doc3.ref_id;

        userCollection.register({username:req.body.username,
           level:current_level,
           parent_id: parent_id,
           ref_id:"REF"+create_ref_id(),
           ttl_chldrn:0,
           points:0,
           pnts_rdmd_till_date: 0,
           pnts_rdmd_this_month: 0 ,
           jng_date: Date.now(),
          }, req.body.password, async function(err, newDoc){
              if(err){
                resp.render("signup", {signupError:"Server error. Please try later."});
              }
              else{
                currentUser=newDoc;
                passport.authenticate("local")(req, resp, async function(){
                  resp.redirect("/userprofile");

                  //interestingly, $inc is working as expected here:
                  userCollection.updateOne({ref_id:parent_id}, {$inc:{ttl_chldrn: 1}}, async function(){

                    var rem_points=20
                    var ref_id=parent_id;

                    for(let CL=current_level-1; CL>=current_level-4; CL--){
                      //facing the issue here:
                      await userCollection.findOneAndUpdate({ref_id: ref_id, level:CL},{$inc:{points:4}}, function(errDoc1, doc1){
                        if (!errDoc1){
                          ref_id=doc1.parent_id;
                          rem_pts=rem_pts-4;
                        }
                      });
                    }
                    //facing the issue here as well:
                     await userCollection.updateOne({username: "Prince"},{$inc:{points:rem_pts}});

                    });
                  });
                  }
                });
              });
            });
          }
    catch(err){
      resp.render("signup", {signupError:"Server error. Please try later."});
    }
  });
});
```

I'm debugging using console.log (which I omitted here) at pretty much every step and I dont see any query running twice. Although I suspect it might be async/await issue because $inc works as expected when I remove the 'await', but then removing 'await' renders other issues you know.

Comment: My guess is you're debugging a route on your server and due to the added debugging listener it's being called twice. the syntax is correct as is, you are just the update is just being called twice.

Comment: nop, its running just once.

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely being called twice. You may think its not, but it is ;)

One thing you can do is add a precondition so it doesn't update twice at the same time. Such as this:

```
model.updateOne(
  {
    username: "Jamie",
    points: 25 // this will fail to match if the points change
  },
  { $inc: { points: 5 } }
)
```

Then the question is, how is it running twice without you knowing it. Are you running it via a queue handler such as SQS? If so, SQS does not guarantee single delivery and you have to ensure that your code is idempotent. Same story with various other methods of execution.

How are you debugging it also? Gonna need more code and context to help further but in general `$inc` will only incrememt the value by the number you specify so for you to increment by 5 and get 10 added strongly implies that its being called twice.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I was mixing await with callback. Await works only when promise is returned. So I removed the callback. Below is the correct code:

```
 var rem_points=20
 var ref_id=parent_id;

for(let CL=current_level-1; CL>=current_level-4; CL--){

  const findAndUpdateQuery=await userCollection.findOneAndUpdate({ref_id: ref_id, level:CL},{$inc:{points:4}}).exec()

  ref_id=findAndUpdateQuery.parent_id;
  rem_pts=rem_pts-4;

}

const updateQuery=await userCollection.updateOne({username: "Prince"},{$inc:{points:rem_pts}}).exec();
console.log("modified docs: "+updateQuery.nModified);
```